# Delphi 10 Firemonkey - Can't Drag and drop Tedits from adoTable

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using the FireMonkey Metropolis UI to make an application, but I can't drag the AdoTable Fields as Tedits to my form to make a register sheet or something like this. Apparently in the VCL or any other Projects this works. How I do this in FireMonkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not OTA support of DBField for firemonkey.
You have to do it manually or use the binding stuff to achieve.

Comment: I've done it with liveBinding already, but the AutoIncrement PrimaryKey doesn't work properly.